# Opencv C++ g++ MakeFile for faster compiling

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, makefile, g++

I'm working on a OpenCV Project that contains some files placed in different Directories (sorted by context)
i would like to avoid to compile all my files each time, because on my Broadwell-E take about 2 minutes and that is a big waste of time if only 1 line in 1 file is edited.

I've already searched on StackOverflow, but i found only makefiles that allow to compile with a shorter command than the full g++ command, they doesn't speed up the compile process.

and i would like to take advantage of my CPU Cores (make -j 13)

targets:

-- all

-- clean

-- run (run 'all' target & Execute the Compiled file)

Answer (score 0):

Install `ccache`, see if it improves your compile time. Read more [here](https://ccache.samba.org/).